# Optimizing Threshold Selection for Improved Sensitivity in Classification Method Without Validated data

Tags: classification, biostatistics, threshold, sensitivity-specificity

Assume we have a datasheet `X`, this datasheet contains many of samples with different gorup like `G1`, `G2`, `G3` and could be classify as type `A` and type `B`.

A common classification method is to use a widely accepted function `ES(x)` to calculate the enrichment score (`E-score`) for all samples in `X` across all groups. The `E-score` follows a normal distribution, and samples with **higher** E-scores are generally considered more likely to belong to Type `B`.

But Its hard to choose a cutoff of `E-score`, The reason is that due to some biological constraints, it is difficult for us to obtain a set of samples that are similar in nature to X and have undergone reliable classification for evaluating different thresholds.

In practice, a common approach is to select a conservative threshold, such as $zscore(Escore) > 3$ or top 10%. This sacrifices sensitivity but retains specificity. In most cases, researchers are satisfied with the specificity of this threshold.

Now, I want to try to find a better way to set this threshold in order to improve the sensitivity of the method.

My samples have some additional characteristics that may be utilized. For example, from a biological perspective, the proportion of type B samples in G1, G2, and G3 should be increasing. However, the specific trend or ratio cannot be determined.